# Performing operations between two lists of vectors in R

Tags: r, list, function, vector

I have two large `lists` with 1000 `elements` each, for example:

```
list.A
$ V1    : num [1:141089] 1 2 3 4 5 ...
$ V2    : num [1:141089] 2 1 4 3 6 ...
$ ..
$ V1000 : num [1:141089] 5 6 7 8 9 ...


list.B
$ V1    : num [1:141089] 5 4 3 2 1 ...
$ V2    : num [1:141089] 4 5 2 3 0 ...
$ ..
$ V1000 : num [1:141089] 9 8 7 6 5 ...
```

[see list.A example figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXuzJ.png)

I would like to perform operations for n<sup>th</sup> `vector` in one `list` by all `vector` in the second `list`.
For instance: `V1` in `list.A` against `V1` in `list.B`, `V2` in `list.B`, until `V1000` in `list.B`. And the same for `V2` until `V1000` in `list.A`.

So far, here is how my code looks like.

```
list.diff <- Map(function(num1, num2) sum(abs(num1 - num2)/20)/(141089), list.A, list.B)
```

By using `Map` in R, I can only perform operations for n<sup>th</sup> `vector` in one list by the n<sup>th</sup> `vector` in the second list. For instance, `V1` in `list.A` against `V1` in `list.B`, and then `V2` in `list.A` against `V2` in `list.B`.

Any suggestions how to solve this? I am new to R and stackoverflow. Many thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use nested `lapply()` and `sapply()` calls:

```
set.seed(13)

list.A <- setNames(
  replicate(3, sample(0:9, 3, replace = TRUE), simplify = FALSE),
  paste0("V", 1:3)
)

list.B <- setNames(
  replicate(3, sample(0:9, 3, replace = TRUE), simplify = FALSE),
  paste0("V", 1:3)
)

list.diff <- lapply(
  list.A, 
  \(num1) sapply(list.B, \(num2) mean(abs(num1 - num2)/20))
)

list.diff
```

```
$V1
       V1        V2        V3 
0.2666667 0.1166667 0.1833333 

$V2
       V1        V2        V3 
0.2333333 0.1500000 0.1833333 

$V3
        V1         V2         V3 
0.15000000 0.13333333 0.06666667
```

Note, I also simplified `sum(...)/141089` to `mean(...)`.